# How to connect 3 table?

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, sqlsrv, eloquent-relationship

In my case, I have three tables:

- `type`

  - id
  - type
  - reason_id
- `reason`

  - id
  - reason
- `permission`

  - id
  - type_id
  - reason_id (not sure has or not)

I expect that:

```json
{
    "message": "Get all permissions with type and reason",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "types": [
                "id": "1",
                "type": "Sick",
                "reasons": [
                    "id": "1",
                    "reason": "covid-19"
                ]
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Please show what you tried so far. Otherwise, nobody will help you.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel try this:

```php
Reason::select(
    'reasons.id as reasonId',
    'reasons.reason as reason',
    'types.id as typeId',
    'types.type as type',
    'permissions.id as permissionId',
)
    ->join('types', 'reasons.id', '=', 'types.reason_id')
    ->join('permissions', 'types.id', '=', 'permissions.type_id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$getDetailsLike = City::leftJoin('states as ST', 'ST.id', '=', 'cities.state_id')
        ->leftJoin('countries as CO', 'CO.id', '=', 'ST.country_id')
        ->where('CO.id', 101)
        ->where('ST.id', 4030)
        ->where('cities.name', 'LIKE', '%nagar%')
        ->select('cities.*', 'ST.id as state_new_id', 'ST.name as state_name', 'CO.id as country_new_id', 'CO.name as country_name')
        ->get();
```